# Is it possible to protect a database from being deleted in Azure?

Tags: database, azure

I have one production database and a test database. Now and then I delete the test database, and make a fresh duplicate from the production db.

I am pretty scared that at a brainless moment I will by accident delete the production database.

I know that you can restore a deleted database, but even the downtime can be quite catastrophic at certain moments in time.

Is it possible to give it an extra lock or some other way to prevent me from deleting this database by accident?

Comment: You can have an user with lowered permission

Comment: @Andre only in the new portal (https://portal.azure.com/). And this user however will not be able to delete the test DB either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an error prone point-and-click interface but instead write a script to delete the test database. You can use either:

- [Azure Powershell](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)
- [Azure Cross-Platform CLI](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/)

You'll be absolutely safe because you won't have a script to delete the production database !

Answer (score 0):

Dirk - you don't say if this is SQL Server on a VM or an Azure SQL Databsae.

If you are using Azure SQL Database and are using one of the new tiers (Basic, Standard or Premium) you can recover deleted databases back to the point at which they were deleted. The duration these deleted databases are held for depends on tier (7 days Basic, 14 days Standard, 35 days Premium). Full details on the [Azure documentation website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj650016.aspx).